# Replace multiple unique string items in a set with multiple other string items at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I have a set of names:

```
>>> name_set = {'A.C. Johnson',
 'Adrian Jefferson',
 'Albus Jung',
 'Al Frank',
 'Alex English',
 'Allen Peters'}
>>> type(name_set)  
set
```

Some of the names need to be adjusted. For example, I need:

```
name_set = {'A.C. Johnson15',
 'Adrian Jefferson',
 'Albus Jung',
 'Al Frank',
 'Alex English40',
 'Allen Peters35'}
```

I've tried:

```
name_set.remove("A.C. Johnson")
name_set.add("A.C. Johnson15")
```

I'm trying to avoid repeating this^ so
I've also tried:

```
fixed_name_set = [name.replace('A.C. Johnson', 'A.C. Johnson15') for name in name_set]
```

This^ is one line, but still requires repetition to replace multiple names. So I've tried something like:

```
fixed_name_set = [name.replace(('A.C. Johnson', 'A.C. Johnson15'), ('Alex English', 'Alex English40')) for name in combined_top_players]
```

A solution similar to this^ would be ideal, but yields `TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly`
What is a pythonic solution to replacing the multiple unique strings with another value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [difference](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) and [union](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) `set` operations to remove/add multiple set elements at once, e.g:

```
>>> name_set = {'A.C. Johnson15', 'Adrian Jefferson', 'Albus Jung', 'Al Frank', 'Alex English40', 'Allen Peters35'}
>>> name_set - {'A.C. Johnson', 'Alex English'} | {'A.C. Johnson15',  'Alex English40'}
{'Albus Jung', 'A.C. Johnson15', 'Allen Peters35', 'Al Frank', 'Adrian Jefferson', 'Alex English40'}
```

Or using set methods:

```
>>> name_set.difference(['A.C. Johnson', 'Alex English']).union(['A.C. Johnson15', 'Alex English40'])
{'Albus Jung', 'A.C. Johnson15', 'Allen Peters35', 'Al Frank', 'Adrian Jefferson', 'Alex English40'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a readable way using python [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
>>> to_fix = { 'A.C. Johnson': 'A.C. Johnson15', 
...            'Alex English': 'Alex English40' }
>>> name_set = {'A.C. Johnson',
...  'Adrian Jefferson',
...  'Albus Jung',
...  'Al Frank',
...  'Alex English',
...  'Allen Peters'}
>>> new_nameset = { to_fix.get( x,x ) for x in name_set }
```

At this time, `new_nameset` contains:

```
{'Adrian Jefferson', 
'Allen Peters', 
'Al Frank', 
'Albus Jung', 
'Alex English40', 
'A.C. Johnson15'}
```